# Arcore crashes when I run it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't understand why this code that I tried to implement gives me an error, or rather, when I compile it it doesn't give me an error, but on the phone it suddenly stops. what can I do? this is the phone error when i start the app:

```
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi / cepheus / cepheus: 10 / QKQ1.190825.002 / V11.0.7.0.QFACNXM: user / release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2020-03-21 00: 30: 49 + 0100
pid: 11048, tid: 11048, name: .Lamiaapp >>> com.example.Lamiaapp <<<
uid: 10264
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    x0 0000000000000000 x1 0000000000002b28 x2 0000000000000006 x3 0000007fc0dd0c50
    x4 5700631b6e123c00 x5 5700631b6e123c00 x6 5700631b6e123c00 x7 803c12ee1be38057
    x8 00000000000000f0 x9 6889a1f9cca4c795 x10 0000000000000001 x11 0000000000000000
    x12 fffffff0fffffbdf x13 0000000000000001 x14 0000000000000008 x15 000078264294907b
    x16 000000755132b738 x17 0000007551309d20 x18 0000000000000120 x19 0000000000002b28
    x20 0000000000002b28 x21 00000000ffffffff x22 ffffffffffffffffff x23 00000074673ff000
    x24 ffffffffffffffff x25 00000075534ab020 x26 00000074ce669cb0 x27 0000000000000002
    x28 0000007fc0dd1030 x29 0000007fc0dd0cf0
    sp 0000007fc0dd0c30 lr 00000075512bb404 pc 00000075512bb430

backtrace:
      # 00 pc 0000000000073430 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort + 160) (BuildId: 084c8a81b8c78e19cd9a1ff6208e77cf)
      # 01 pc 000000000005d328 /data/app/com.example.Lamiaapp-d66o-3Pho4pDNhEP165jhg==/lib/arm64/libfilament-jni.so (BuildId: 977540993aee4379ce0a55c2c49d0b77d70be50f)
```

While this is the code of the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArFragment arFragment;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

            arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

                ModelRenderable.builder()
                        .setSource(this, Uri.parse("ArcticFox_Posed.sfb"))
                        .build()
                        .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor,modelRenderable))
                        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
                                    .show();
                            return null;
                        });
            });

}

private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.select();

}


}
```

Comment: Compilation is no guarantee of correctness, and your exception points to `Lamiaapp` (snakes?) and native code. Does your android studio plugin version match your sceneform sdk? A quick Google search led [here](https://gitmemory.com/issue/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/866/531815670) where tpsiaki commented *The 1.12 Android Studio plugin is only compatible with SFB files converted with Sceneform SDK 1.12 because of Filament material version changes.*

Comment: "Lamiaapp" Is the name of my app. But do I have to install only the plug-in for Sceneform or is there anything else?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Sceneform. Don't know where your SFB file came from. But your specific error led me to that quote. And the implication is if your SFB file came from a different version then it **can** cause your specific error.

Comment: HAVE YOU FOUND ANY SOLUTION